# Regular expression, is this possible?

Tags: regex

So far I have:

```
^[1-6],[1-6]$
```

The above will permit a comma delimited expression of two numbers where each number must be between 1 and 6.

Is it possible to include a comparison in the expression which would mean that the first number must be exactly 1 less than the second number and that the first number and second numbers must be different?

Comment: No, spell out the alternatives, `^(?:1,2|2,3|3,4|4,5|5,6)$`

Comment: brute force method: `^(1,2|2,3|3,4|4,5|5,6)$`

Comment: No. Since from Regex's point of view, it is dealing with a string not a number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is the "?:" required?

Comment: No, but it is the best practice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ok, slight variant, how would I modify the expression to allow optional multiples of the same following the same rules, e.g. 1,2,3,4 or 4,5,6 ?

Comment: i think @anubhava could set its comment as answer ( [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Byh6L/1) )

Comment: No, regular expressions do not do mathematical calculations.

Comment: @SPlatten "?:" is not required, and it is not "best practice".  It tells the engine to not save that grouping in a variable that you can use later.  Using "?:" will save you milliseconds, but if you don't care about that, then don't clutter up your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top comments are correct: there is no way other than "brute force" or "spelling out" alternatives as there is no way to do math inside a regular expression.

Use any version, with capturing or [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions):

```js
^(?:1,2|2,3|3,4|4,5|5,6)$
^(1,2|2,3|3,4|4,5|5,6)$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/CG4ihl/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1,2                      '1,2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2,3                      '2,3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3,4                      '3,4'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    4,5                      '4,5'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5,6                      '5,6'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```